# Does a sequence satisfying this condition converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

> Prove or disprove: if for every $n\in\Bbb{N}, |a_{n+1}-a_n|<\frac{1}{n^2}$ then $a_n$ converges.

I think this is true, and tried using Cauchy's theorem - I take some $\varepsilon > 0$. There exists such $N$ s.t $\varepsilon > \frac{1}{N^2}$. So, for every $m,n>N$, we get that:
$|a_m-a_n|\leq|a_m-a_{m-1}|+...+|a_{n+1}-a_n|<\frac{1}{m^2}+...+\frac{1}{n^2}<\frac{m-n}{N^2}$. Now I think the righthand side tends to $0$, but this feels like cheating. Am I correct or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Do you mean a _sequence_ rather than a series?

Comment: @Miguel Yes, edited it

Comment: Why does the RHS converge?  What if $m$ is very large with respect to $n$?  You’ve been a bit too strong handed with the approximation.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes this is why it feels like cheating. If the statement is indeed true this is not the way to prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use Cauchy criterion here.

The fact that $|a_{n+1}-a_n| \leq 1/n^2$ implies that the *series* $\sum (a_{n+1}-a_n)$ is absolutely convergent, hence convergent, hence the sequence $(a_n)$ converges.

Comment: I wish I had thought of that. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Note that for all sufficiently large $n$ and all $m > n$, we have

$$|a_m-a_n| \leqslant \sum_{k=n}^m \frac{1}{k^2} \leqslant \int_{n-1}^m \frac{dx}{x^2} = \frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{m} < \frac{1}{n-1} < \epsilon$$

Answer (score 0):

Take $\varepsilon>0$. Since the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$ converges, there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac1{n^2}<\varepsilon$ . So, if $m\geqslant n\geqslant N$,\begin{align}|a_m-a_n|&\leqslant\frac1{(m-1)^2}+\frac1{(m-2)^2}+\cdots+\frac1{n^2}\\&<\sum_{k=N}^\infty\frac1{k^2}\\&<\varepsilon.\end{align}So, your sequence converges, since it is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: The question is about $a_n$ not $\sum a_n$

Comment: What do you think now?